# minio: What is the cluster architecture of minio.io object storage server?

Tags: amazon-s3, storage, openstack, minio

I have searched minio.io for hours but id dosn't provide any good information about clustering, dose it has rings and instance are connected? or mini is just for single isolated machine. And for running a cluster we have to run many isolated instance of it and the our app choose to which instance we write?

if yes: 
When I write a file to a bucket does minio replicate it between multi server?
I is it like amazon s3, or openstack swift that support of storing multi copy of object in different servers (and not multi disk on the same machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, minio does not support clustering with automatic replication across multiple servers, balancing, etcetera.

However, the minio documentation does say how you can set up one minio server to *mirror* another one:

- https://gitlab.gioxa.com/opensource/minio/blob/1983925dcfc88d4140b40fc807414fe14d5391bd/docs/setup-replication-between-two-sites-running-minio.md

Comment: Thanks your link was useful.

Comment: Link is broken :(

Comment: Yea.  It is gone.

Answer (score 13):

Here is the document for distributed minio: https://docs.minio.io/docs/distributed-minio-quickstart-guide

Comment: Any idea when minio-distributed will be released as stable?

Answer (score 0):

Minio also Introduced Continuous Availability and Active-Active Bucket Replication. Checkout[Their active-active Replication Guide](https://blog.min.io/active-active-replication/)